# Get pass to htpasswd automatically via php or htaccess

Tags: .htpasswd

I am trying to get pass to htpasswd automatically via php (as curl do using CURLOPT_USERPWD).

I have referred many solutions mentioned on stackoverflow. But nothing is working.

Currently I am using this code in .htaccess

```
# set the NOPASSWD variable if the request is for a specific URI
SetEnvIf Request_URI "uri/<path>/*" NOPASSWD=true

AuthType Basic
AuthName "Password Protected Area"
AuthUserFile /<path>.htpasswd
Require valid-user
Order Deny,Allow
Satisfy any
Deny from all
Allow from env=NOPASSWD
```

Important: I want to skip url for a specific controller where my iphone and Andriod app webservice is defined. So that any link on the website ask for user and password but our Apps keep working.

I want to bypass password set by htaccess automatically using htaccess or by php. Anything which work.

Please help.